# How can I create an Azure AD Application Key?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

Is it somehow possible to create an Azure AD Application Key via `PowerShell`?

I could not really find any working solution. Currently I have this piece of code:

```
$appName = "myAppName"
$password = "myPassword"

$app = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName $appName -HomePage "https://$appName" -IdentifierUris "https://$appName" -Password $password
New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId

New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName "Data Factory Contributor" -ServicePrincipalName $app.ApplicationId
```

This all works fine so far but I also need to create a Key for the app for clients to actually access it. In the Azure portal this would be under `MyDirectory --> App registrations --> myAppName --> Settings --> Keys`

also I am not quite sure what the Password for the application is actually used for?!

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found this blog post and it seems to solve my issue:
https://www.sabin.io/blog/adding-an-azure-active-directory-application-and-key-using-powershell/